# filter mongodb object result by ObjectId with Underscore

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js

I have a problem combining  UnderscoreJS and MongooseJS in NodeJS. I have a result of mongoose and I want filter a array

```
var __ = require("underscore"),
    platformInfo = __.findWhere(user.platforms, {"pId": platformId});
```

But pId inside user.platforms is a ObjectId and can't find.
But if i make a each and compare like this all its OK:

```
__.each(user.platforms, function(platform){

                if(platform.pId.toString() == platformId){

                }

});
```

How i can find in findWhere method (one line, and cool) the same result? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Sadly mongodb ObjectId instances do not work properly with JavaScript's equality operators `==` or `===`. You either need to use the provided method: `objectId1.equals(objectId2)` or ensure they are both converted to strings and then underscore or `===` will work.

```
platformInfo = _.filter(user.platforms, function (platform) {
  return platform.pId.toString() === platformId;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write a general function for that problem using underscore.js:

```
function findWhereObjectId(objs, comp) {
    return _.find(objs, function(obj) {
        return _.some(_.keys(obj), function(key) {
            return (key == _.keys(comp)[0] && obj[key].equals(comp[key]));
        });
    });
};
```

You could now call `findWhereObjectId(user.platforms, {"pId": platformId})` and it should give you the first match.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, mongodb ObjectId instances do not work properly with JavaScript's equality operators.
However, there's another simpler solution for this problem: You could take your MongoDB result object and convert it to a string via JSON.stringify():

```
    var myString = JSON.stringify(MONGODB_RESULT);
```

After that you can convert that string back to an object via JSON.parse():

```
    var myObject = JSON.parse(myString);
```

You can now perform any Lodash/Underscore operation on that object.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .toString after id of mongo response obbject
For ex

`_.findWhere(allMappingData, {_categoryId: catObj._id.toString() ,_contentId: content.contentId.toString()}));`